# How to set custom width of a candlestick in highstock

Tags: highcharts

How to set custom width of each candlestick in Highstock chart?

Comment: Set series.pointWidth - https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/series.candlestick.pointWidth

Answer (score 1):

Hey I set pointWidth = 1 but still has 4 px wide bars, but when I set it to a bigger number, bars do expand

```
series: [
  {
    type: 'candlestick',
    lineWidth: 0,
    pointWidth: 1,
    data: [...]
  }
]
```

did you encounter this?

[image: 4 px width bars]